# Error cound not find all functions in the R program

Tags: r

This is the program however when I run it says cannot find function dbSendQuery or dbCoonect or any function in the program.I am not sure is it due to me not installing the right packages

```
 install.packages("RMySQL")

library(RMySQL)






mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname='W1547901_0', user='',password='',host='elephant.ecs.westminster.ac.uk')

dbSendQuery(mydb, "drop table if exists books")
# creating tables in bookstore:

dbSendQuery(mydb, "
            CREATE TABLE books (
            book_id INT,
            title VARCHAR(50),
            publisher VARCHAR(50));")



dbListTables(mydb)

dbSendQuery(mydb, "INSERT INTO books
            (book_id, title, publisher)
            VALUES(1, 'R and MySQL', 'Addison Wesley');")

try1 = fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT book_id, title, publisher
FROM books
                         WHERE book_id = 1 ;"))
```

Comment: Those functions are in the DBI package,  not RMySQL.

Comment: DBI should be loaded as it is a required dependency of RMySQL. Make sure `library(RMySQL)` call completes without any errors and warnings. It is better to use `library("RMySQL")` (inside double quotes) to eliminate problems in case `RMySQL` is a defined variable in the current environment.